# ngClass and onClick Not Applying to Div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, angular11

I have a javascript project that I'm trying to convert into Angular and I'm having trouble understanding why the classes some of my are making the menu disappear even after reading the documentation again. I want the menu I have to rotate into and X only if .menu-btn is clicked on.

Here is the javascript code I'm trying to convert:

```
 // Select DOM Items
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const menuNav = document.querySelector(".menu-nav");
const menuBranding = document.querySelector(".menu-branding");
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");

// Set Initial State Of Menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("close");
    menu.classList.add("show");
    menuNav.classList.add("show");
    menuBranding.classList.add("show");
    navItems.forEach((item) => item.classList.add("show"));

    // Set Menu State
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove("close");
    menu.classList.remove("show");
    menuNav.classList.remove("show");
    menuBranding.classList.remove("show");
    navItems.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("show"));

    // Set Menu State
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<header>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="menu-btn" [class.menu-btn.close]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Overlay that comes up when you click menu -->
    
          <!-- Profile Image put in through CSS -->
          <nav class="menu" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
            <div class="menu-branding" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
            </div>
           
            <!-- Pages -->
            <ul class="menu-nav" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                <li class="nav-item current" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                    <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                    <a href="work.html" class="nav-link">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" [class.menu-btn.show]="check" (click)="myfunction()">
                    <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

app.component.scss

```
     $primary-color: red;
$secondary-color: blue;

@mixin easeOut {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.container{
  background-color: grey;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;

}
.btn-line{
  color:blue;
}


header{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
  width:100%;
}

.menu-btn{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:3;
  right:35px;
  top:35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  @include easeOut;

  .btn-line{
    width: 28px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    background: white;
    @include easeOut;
  
  }
  //Rotate Into X with Menu Lines
  &.close {
    transform: rotate(180deg);

    .btn-line {
      // Line 1 - Rotate
      &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
      }

      // Line 2 - Hide
      &:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      // Line 3 - Rotate
      &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -6px);
      }
    }
  }
}

.btn-line{
  color:black;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'menu';

   check:boolean=true;
  
    myfunction(){
      this.check=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems `check` is initially set to true, so nothing is ever changing.

Comment: I have it set to true because if I set it to false then the lines for the hamburger menu are not visible. @Silvermind

Comment: Does this fix your issue?
    myfunction(){
      this.check = !this.check;
    }

Comment: No, it just makes the hamburger menu lines disappear. I want the lines to transform into an X when clicked and if clicked again, they should turn back into 3 stacked lines in the shape of a hamburger menu. @bjlasc01

Comment: Your original `toggleMenu` function adds classes to other elements, your angular code and template do not.

Comment: I had all of the classes but I got ride of them since the menu was not working the way I wanted it to. I updated the question to what I have now, even after adding all of the classes the menu still disappears. @AviadP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simple answer is that you cannot add two classes at once with the `[class.xxx.yyy]` directive...

If you want both classes applied you have to do it in two separate `[class...]` directives, or use an `ngClass` directive, e.g. `[ngClass]="{ xxx: check, yyy: check }"`

**EDIT (following comment)** your template has stuff such as `[class.menu-btn.show]="check"` I must have guessed wrong when I assumed that you wanted to add both the `show` and the `menu-btn` class based on the value of the variable `check` - if that wasn't your intention, I'm sorry. But at any rate, the class you wish to add must be the sole name in that directive (after `class.`), so if you want to add the `show` class, do `[class.show]="check"`. And you can use multiple such directives, each for a different class.

Comment: Can you give a small example? I'm not trying to add 2 classes at once, one class is already applied and I just wanted to add another only if the user clicks the menu.

Comment: The issue that I had was I kept adding both the name of the class I wanted to select (menu) & the class I wanted to add (close). I finally understand how to use the directive properly now, thank you!